# Responsive Images on Wordpress Blog

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive

On this webpage (actually, the entire blog section), some images are responsive, and some are not. When I try to put a max-width on the images, they don't fit within the confines of the parent. Is anyone a little wiser about what could be happening here, especially when it's not happening elsewhere on the site?

Appreciate it!

http://www.sensoft.ca/blog/never-know-youll-find/

Answer (score 0):

Add following CSS to your theme's **Style.css** file:

```
.wp-caption {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```